How to configure my CAP app for oData 2.0 ([ODataMetadata] initial loading of metadata failed)
in my CAP/UI5 app I try to bind data to a TreeTable. As oData 4.0 does not support TreeTables, I thought I need to use oData 2.0. When i change my manifest.json I get the following error and the TreeTable stays empty:
[ODataMetadata] initial loading of metadata failed
Error: Invalid metadata document
The answers in this question were just to use oData 4.0 instead. As oData 2.0 is still supported, I am wondering what am I doing wrong. Is there a configuration in my CAP App I have overseen? For example the metadata document uses some version 4.0, could this be the problem?
manifest.json:
"dataSources": {
  "mainService": {
    "uri": "/browse/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
      "annotations": [],
      "odataVersion": "2.0"
    }
  }
}

"models": {
  ...
  "": {
    "dataSource": "mainService",
    "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
    "preload": true,
    "settings": {
      "synchronizationMode": "None",
      "operationMode": "Server",
      "autoExpandSelect": true,
      "earlyRequests": true
    }
  }
},


